# Why doesn't my Full text search yields results?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

I have a simple `View`:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/fb0OKx0.png]

Let's select top 5 rows : (the view  doesn't have `top 5` - it's just for clarity here)

```
SELECT TOP 5 [CustomerId]
      ,[EngLastFirst]
      ,[EngFirstLast]
      ,[LocalLastFirst]
      ,[LocalFirstLast]
  FROM [WebERP].[dbo].[View_CustomersNames]
```

Result :

[image]

Let's create a Full Text Index (*Right click on the `view`*):

[image]

OK. so now we also have a `catalog` :

Right click on the `catalog` - to see properties :

[image]

All the properties are `default` :

[image]

Let's click `rebuild` on the `catalog`:

[image]

**Great**

Let's run a simple `CONTAINS` query  :

```
SELECT * FROM View_CustomersNames vcn 
        where CONTAINS( vcn.*, '"aerSwy*"')
```

As you see from earlier code - the record does exists :

[image]

**But** it returns **no** results

While `like` does return results:

```
SELECT * FROM View_CustomersNames vcn 
        where  vcn.engLAstFirst LIKE '%aerSwy%'
```

[image]

**Question:**

Why I'm not getting result for this query ?

```
SELECT * FROM View_CustomersNames vcn 
        where CONTAINS( vcn.*, '"aerSwy*"')
```

NB - I might be missing something which is *very* basic (new to Full Text Search)

**Edit**

In production environment  - it does work. in my local environment - it doesn't

[image]

Comment: I don't know anything about full text search, but perhaps the search term should use the % wildcard instead of *

Comment: @Origin (msdn) : http://i.imgur.com/hB7m0Cz.png

Comment: Your view is selecting only 5 records from the table with no ORDER BY which can cause random results. It's possible that the record you're expecting is not in that top 5, either when querying or at index time. Try removing TOP 5 from the view.

Comment: Is there a difference in the default language between local and production?

Comment: SO should freeze the downvoter activity for a month. I have never seen such detailed question in SO. ( regardless myne or not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem — It was permissions

Here :

[image]

And now the `CONTAINS` works :

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should remove TOP 5 from your view. I don't believe that will work in SQL. Order your results however you need to like Keith said. Here is a link to some basic SQL examples. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_quickref.asp Try using some of these as a reference when reconstructing your statements. These should help guide you on manipulating your sql to do what you need it to. also, I don't think you need to put the name of the database after you reference the table name in your SQL statement.

Comment: it was just an example. the view dowsn't have top 5. this is not the problem I mentioned